Map tensor elements by dictionary in Pytorch
I have a tensor that is:
t = torch.tensor([1, 2, 3])

and a mapping:
mapping = {1: 0.2, 2: 1.2, 3: 3.0}

I want to map the element in t by mapping so the expected result will be
torch.tensor([0.2, 1.2, 3.0])

Is there an efficient way of doing this? In Tensorflow could use for example tf.lookup.StaticHashTable.
Thanks for any help.

Are your keys always integer values or could they be floats? Are the keys relatively static or dynamic?

@Karl Yes, my key is always integer. The keys are relatively static.

Tensors have a "put_" method requiring 2 arguments:

A Long tensor of indices
A tensor of values

i.e.
indices = torch.tensor(list(mapping.keys()),dtype=torch.long)
values  = torch.tensor(list(mapping.values()))

t.put_(indices,values)

speedup of about 10-15x over manual indexing.
Graph of speedup
